# summarise totals numeric cols wrt to categorical col using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, janitor

I am trying to summarise the following dataset....
here is the `dput`

```r
structure(list(sentiment_desc = c("positive", "negative", "negative", 
"negative", "negative", "negative", "negative", "positive", "positive", 
"negative", "positive", "positive", "negative", "negative", "negative", 
"positive", "positive", "positive", "positive", "positive"), 
    relationship = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), portfolio = c(0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), vfm = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ease = c(0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Innovation = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), Customer_Focus = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), people = c(1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

At the bottom row. I want to show the total i.e. `sum` for each column from `relationship` column to `people`. Just adding if there was one... and then count how many `negative`, `positve` were within each `col`. For example: `relation col` total is `18` and `10` were `positive` and `8` were `negatives`

How could I achieve this? 
I know there is a janitor and this is what I have tried:

```r
adorn_totals(df, where = "col", na.rm = TRUE,
  name = "Total")
```

but this shows weird output...

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by `sentiment_desc` and then summarise all column by calculating the sum :

```r
library(dplyr)
Sum <- df %>% group_by(sentiment_desc) %>% summarise_if(is.numeric, ~sum(.)) %>%
  mutate(sentiment_desc = paste(sentiment_desc,"Total"))

# A tibble: 2 x 8
  sentiment_desc relationship portfolio   vfm  ease Innovation Customer_Focus people
  <chr>                 <int>     <int> <int> <int>      <dbl>          <dbl>  <dbl>
1 negative Total            8         5     1     4          1              5      7
2 positive Total           10         4     1     2          6              7      8
```

And then use `bind_rows` to get the two lines adding at the end of your dataframe:

```r
library(dplyr)
DF <- df %>% bind_rows(Sum)

tail(DF)
# A tibble: 6 x 8
  sentiment_desc relationship portfolio   vfm  ease Innovation Customer_Focus people
  <chr>                 <int>     <int> <int> <int>      <dbl>          <dbl>  <dbl>
1 positive                  1         0     0     0          1              0      1
2 positive                  1         0     0     1          0              1      1
3 positive                  1         1     0     0          0              1      0
4 positive                  1         0     0     0          1              1      1
5 negative Total            8         5     1     4          1              5      7
6 positive Total           10         4     1     2          6              7      8
```

Does it look what you are trying to do ?

Comment: awesome! thanks @dc37. kicking myself for not thinking this myself